# Is there a phrase for when you "bite the bullet" on a logical consequence but maintain that it's not a "bullet" at all?

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, rhetoric

Opponents of a view often attempt to draw outrageous logical consequences from the view in order to discredit it: if *p* leads to something as outrageous as *q*, then that just shows that *p* is false. Defenders of the view can try to show that it doesn't actually entail the alleged logical consequence, or they can “bite the bullet” and sorrowfully admit that the view really does entail the outrageous logical consequence while at the same time maintaining that the view (despite its regrettably outrageous implications) should be accepted anyway. But defenders sometimes have another response available: admit that the view really does entail the allegedly outrageous consequence while maintaining that in fact this consequence is not outrageous but perfectly plausible in its own right. (For example: a radical says there's no such thing as free will, a traditionalist says such a view entails that punishment of criminals is wrong and that prisons should be abolished, and the radical responds by gladly and not regretfully “biting the bullet” on those consequences.)

I’m wondering if there are any phrases used to describe this last kind of response. Something like “biting the bullet but saying it’s ice cream” or “biting the bullet with a smile on your face” or (as the defender might put it) “a delicious bullet to bite”—only hopefully not as dumb as these phrases I just came up with.

Comment: _Bite the bullet_ doesn't mean 'accept unpalatable facts', it means 'make up your mind to do something necessary but unpleasant that you have been putting off".

Comment: @KateBunting - If you search Google Scholar for _"bite the bullet" argument premise conclusion_, you can see lots and lots of examples of the phrase used in the way I'm referring to.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. Just because a few people think "bite the bullet" has some special relevance to conceding a point in an argument doesn't make that part of mainstream English. People can make up any expressions they like in this general area, but whether they're any good or not is just a matter of opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - It's not just "a few people", as can be verified with Google Scholar.

Comment: Whether it is or not doesn't really affect my closevote, which is predicated on the fact that the merits of any suggestions are just a matter of opinion. There is no unambiguously "correct" answer.

Comment: Could you start by outlining what 'Bite the bullet' means to you?

Comment: [This Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bite_the_bullet) explains the term reasonably well.  In a scenario where a wounded soldier needs to have battlefield surgery to, eg, remove a bullet, the soldier is given a bullet (solid lead), bullet cartridge (brass), or a piece of leather strap to bite on, helping to relieve the pain of the procedure.

Comment: In the long past British women who did not enjoy intercourse, even with their husbands, were encouraged to keep at it in order that England should have strong sons in the future. And so they were encouraged to *"Close their eyes and think of England"*.

Comment: This seems a reasonable question even if the way it's asked is confused. An expression for maintaining that an undesirable consequence is nothing serious or even to be welcomed (we don't need to do anything about global CO2 emissions because even though global warming seems cataclysmic, the weather here is a bit chilly sometimes).

Answer (score -1):

Simply, *embrace* can be used with the sense 'biting the bullet with a smile on your face'. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/thesaurus/articles/to-accept-or-continue-in-a-situation-that-is-difficult-or-unpleasant) succinctly defines this sense of *embrace* as:

> In formal English, if you embrace a difficult situation, you accept it with a very positive attitude.
>
> - *She embraced her hardships without complaint.*

There are phrases like **brave it out, tough it out** for being courageous in a difficult situation, which *might* work in some cases (and possibly for your context, by conveying the message "facing or accepting the consequences with a brave heart") as the words *brave* and *tough* have a positive sense,  but you don't necesarrily accept the situation with a positive attitude or a smile on your face in these phrases.

A creative approach that came to my mind was modifying the idiom 'bite the bullet' in a way you bite something soft instead of a 'bullet', and I came up with **bite the marshmallow**. To my surprise, I wasn't the only one who've thought of it (excluding the literal usages): [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bite+the+marshmallow%22&client=ms-android-samsung-gs-rev1&biw=412&bih=722&tbm=bks&ei=bYK7ZPfzH__Axc8P7rON-AQ&oq=%22bite+the+marshmallow%22&gs_lp=Eg9tb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXNlcnAiFiJiaXRlIHRoZSBtYXJzaG1hbGxvdyIyBRAhGKABMgUQIRigATIFECEYoAEyCBAhGBYYHhgdMggQIRgWGB4YHTIIECEYFhgeGB1ItWVQ7wVYhmFwBXgAkAECmAG3AaAB5iiqAQQwLjM4uAEDyAEA-AEBigIZbW9iaWxlLWd3cy13aXotc2VycC1tb2Rlc6gCAMICBRAAGIAEwgIHEAAYigUYQ8ICBhAAGAcYHsICBhAAGBYYHsICCBAAGBYYHhgPwgILEAAYFhgeGPEEGArCAgcQIRigARgKiAYB&sclient=mobile-gws-serp)

People sometimes modify idioms for humor or  to change the tone but it might not always work and you need to use it in a clever way. I've seen this kind of play on idioms in news articles usually.

Comment: I think not. I think 'She embraced her hardships without complaint' is in no useful way different from 'She bit the bullet.'